# The values in drop down is not populated

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-material

I am trying to populate a drop down with data from the database. I am getting the data from the database but I don't know why the drop down is not populated.When I do the console.log the value is[image]:

```
getPdfControls().then(function (response) {
    $scope.PdfControls = response;
});

function getPdfControls() {
    return $http.post(baseUrl + 'Admin/getPdfControls').then(function (response) {
        console.log($.parseJSON(response.data));
        return $.parseJSON(response.data);
    })
}

<md-select ng-model="selected.pdfControl" ng-change="changePdfControl(selected.pdfControl)" required >
    <md-option ng-repeat="pdfControl in pdfControls" value="{{pdfControl.ControlColumn}}">{{pdfControl.ControlText}}</md-option>
</md-select>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$scope.PdfControls = response;` PdfControls start with big P
`ng-repeat="pdfControl in pdfControls"` pdfControls start with small p

Variables & Object properties are case-sensitive